# Unable to create access point using Netsh in windows

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, netsh, internet-sharing

I have try following, to make my lenovo T420 as an access point.

1. First of all I verify my laptop's physical wireless adapter supports this feature using the following command:

   `NETSH WLAN show drivers`

   and it was ok : `Hosted network supported: Yes`
2. Set SSID and Key :

   `NETSH WLAN set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=my_SSID key=my_Passphrase`
3. Activate it:

   `NETSH WLAN start hostednetwork`
4. Share my internet connection with a Hosted Network

but I couldn't connect to the access point as it has no network access.

How can I fix this?

PS: OS : windows 7 Professional - service pack 1

Comment: Once you have that enabled, go to "View Network Connections" Hold down control and select both the hostednetwork and the network that currently has internet. Right click > Bridge connections. This will pass the internet access from one network to the other.

Comment: There is no Bridge option, when I select both of the connection in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" and all the option are disabled.